# How are arguments in C/C++ macros handled implicitly?

Tags: macros, arguments, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to read and understand a file written in C ([here](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/blob/6d135a686a74376495a7a6f55d3d67df54186f83/gramtools/mkdfa/mkfa-1.44-flex/lex.yy.c)) and not knowing much C (or if it's C++ to begin with), I'm wondering how the following:

```
 #define BEGIN yy_start = 1 + 2 *
```

when called like this:

```
 BEGIN(new_state)
```

is working. I know `BEGIN` is a macro/placeholder setting `yy_start`. However I can't find anything on how the argument passed in is handled and  [operands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) don't get me anywhere.

**Question**: How are arguments handled in a C/C++ macro if they are not handled explicitly?

Comment: This is C language, which you can tell by the file extension (C++ uses *.cpp).

Comment: Wouldn't that just resolve to `yy_start = 1 + 2 * (new_state)`, which is just multiplication?

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks for clarification. Can you make it answer, then I will check.

Comment: @Toby:  file extensions are guidlines.  I can use *.cpp or *.frog and pass them to a C++ compiler.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews True! Though it generally is a good indication of what was intended by the author, just as the `*.yy` *generally* indicates yacc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro BEGIN has no arguments so the resulting code will be

```
yy_start = 1 + 2 *(new_state)
```

It is done in preprocessing.

Answer (score 11):

> How are arguments handled in a C/C++ macro if they are not handled explicitly?

If a macro is not declared with arguments then it does not take arguments at all.  Indeed, C explicitly distinguishes between macros that accept arguments and those that don't.  In your particular case, given a definition of `BEGIN` as an object-like macro:

```
#define BEGIN yy_start = 1 + 2 *
```

This invocation ...

```
BEGIN(new_state)
```

... expands to:

```
yy_start = 1 + 2 *(new_state)
```

.  In particular, note that only the macro name is replaced.  The parenthesized tokens following it are not part of the macro invocation, and are not affected by the macro expansion.